# Show loading image while my controller execute a function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

need to show an image while my function "Mailcontroller/sendMail" is working sending an email. I passed values to this function from my view by a submit button in a form. I had try with other examples that I saw here, but I can't get what I need.

My view:

```js
    <div class="container" style="margin-right: 100px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
            <form class="form-horizontal" enctype='multipart/form-data' method="POST" action="<?=base_url();?>Cpersona/sendMail">
                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label style="font-size: 15px; margin-left: 215px;">Destinatarios</label><br />
                          <input type="button" name="agregardes" id="agregardes" onclick="llenarDestino();correos();" style="font-size: 15px; margin-left: 215px;" value="Agregar Destinatarios">
                          <input style="margin-left: 215px;" id="email" name="email" type="text" class="form-control" required>
                          <label style="font-size: 15px; margin-left: 215px;">Asunto</label><br />
                          <input style="margin-left: 215px;" type="text" class="form-control" name="asunto" id="asunto">
                          <label style="font-size: 15px; margin-left: 215px;">Mensaje</label><br />
                      </div>
                    
                      <div class="col-md-9" style="float: right;">
                          <textarea id="editor" name="mensaje"></textarea>
                      </div> 
                  </div>
                  <section>
                      <div style="margin-left: 215px;">
                      <p id="msg"></p>
                      <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
                      </div>
                  </section>

                  <div>
                      <br />
                      <input style="margin-left: 215px;" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>             

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {    
$('#enviar').click(function(){

    //Añadimos la imagen de carga en el contenedor
    $('#content').html('<div><img src="../assets/images/loading.gif"/></div>');

    var page = $(this).attr('data');        
    var dataString = 'page='+page;


    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost/empresa/Cpersona/sendMail",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            //Cargamos finalmente el contenido deseado
            $('#content').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
        }
    });
});              
});    
</script>
```

An extract of my Controller:

```
     public function sendMail{

                $data = array(
                'id_usuario' => $usuario,
                'fecha' => $fecha,
                'id' => $cliente 
                );

            $this->Modelo_datos->historial($data);

            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->from('correopruebas@consultora.cl');
            $this->email->to($value);
            $this->email->subject($asunto);
            $this->email->message($enviar);

            //$path = set_realpath('./uploads/');
            //$adjunto = $path.$archivo;

            if($this->email->send())
             {

                $this->load->helper("file");
                delete_files('./uploads/');
                echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Correo Enviado!!')
                window.location.href='verLista';
                </SCRIPT>");

            }
            else
            {
                 show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                 $this->load->helper("file");
                 delete_files('./uploads/');
            }

        }
```

}

Comment: show some code!

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: sorry, i forget it, now is ok

Comment: open console by hiting CTRL+SHIFT+i and go to console tab and tell me the error you see

Comment: no error displayed, and any image is loaded =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first add image(that you want to be displayed) with id loader and make it hidden by using style="display:none";

```
loader = document.querySelector("#loader");
function sendMail() {
    loader.style.display = "block";
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         loader.style.display="none";
         // some thing here when email is sent
     }
 };
xhttp.open("GET", "your_send_mail_file.php?send=true", true);
xhttp.send();
```

}

and in your_send_mail_file.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["send"]) && $_GET["send"] === "true") {
    $test = new your_class(); // that_contain_the_sendMail function;
    $test->sendMail();
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in xhttp.open("POST", "yoursendmail.php?some_variables_in _post", true); i have no variable on my controller for use here, just $this->email->sendmail() is the function that i want to watch and add a loading image while is executing, so i need to do:  xhttp.open("POST", "Mailcontroller/sendMail", true); ???

Comment: No. ease add your php code without sensitive variables

Comment: an example pls, i newbie on php

Comment: I didn't understand anything of your code but I think this answer should help you

Comment: thank you again! i'm using the php framework "codeigniter", i'll try your code

Comment: I am sorry if my code didn't help you but I didn't learn any php framework I don't know how to use any of them because I usually write my php codes from zero :)

Comment: is ok, i'll try to adapt your code to my code, thank you so much